# add padding to numbers in file name

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a few hundred images, few named like

```
1.jpg
2.jpg 
...... 
11.jpg 
.... 
101.jpg
```

And few others like

```
deer - 1 -spotted.jpg 
deer - 2 - musk.jpg 
..... 
deer - 11 - river.jpg 
.....
```

I would like to rename `1.jpg` to `001.jpg` and `deer - 1.jpg` to `deer - 001.jpg`.

I tried renaming them with while loop bash script but

```
mv deer - 1* deer - 01 - spotted.jpg
selects deer - 1 , deer - 11, deer - 111
```

I am looking for cli way and bash script if possible to rename files like above 
Thank you

Comment: @muru thank you for quick help , should I delete the question as duplicate exists?

Comment: You needn't delete duplicates, it can help others who're searching for similar problems.